# Generate random number while the generated number is on a list - ansible

Tags: list, loops, random, ansible

I'm trying to generate random numbers in ansible while the generated number, exists in a list of numbers.

Let's suppose that my list have this values.

```
list = [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10]
```

I'm using the module `set_fact` like this.

```
- set_fact:
    value: "{{ (1,10) | random }}"
  until: value not in list
```

The value generated using the random rule always generate the number `1` or `10`, I've used the module `debug` like the code below and it always generate different numbers.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ (1,10) | random }}"
```

My problem here is, how can I generate random number in a certain interval, like the one above (1,10) and how can I keep generating random numbers while the generated number exists in the list, when the generated number isn't in the list, i want to stop the loop and use this number for something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very tricky and actually I can't say I have a clean solution for you. First things first, to get a random number from 1 to 10 you have to use:

```
msg: "{{ 10 | random(start=1 }}"
```

The problem is that this task doesn't work as we would expected it, I guess the `until` clause works in mysterious ways (will explain later why):

```
- set_fact:
    value: "{{ 10 | random(start=1) }}"
  until: value not in list
```

Running it a few times, you will realize that the `until` loop is "bypassed" and sometimes you get values that are in the exclusion list `list` variable.

You can try with `include_tasks` to extend the loop to 2 tasks (one to get the random integer, then to assign to your `value` variable if not in the list, but the `until` clause of the `include_tasks` task will still not work.

One workaround solution i found to work is by using a shell command to generate a random number, have that value as the commands "exit code" (as just stdout will not work!!) and if exit code not in the `list` list, then assign it to the `value` var.

The task's code:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_list: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10]  
    
  tasks:
    - name: run shell to get random number
      shell: exit `shuf -i 1-10 -n 1` 
      register: shell_command
      failed_when: shell_command.rc > 100
      until: shell_command.rc not in my_list
      retries: 1000
      delay: 1

    - name: print results
      debug:
        var: shell_command.rc
```

sample run:

```
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# ansible-playbook testt.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [run shell to get random number] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: run shell to get random number (1000 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: run shell to get random number (999 retries left).
changed: [localhost]

TASK [print results] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "shell_command.rc": "8"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]#
```

As stated before, if you use `echo` instead of `exit` in the `shell` command, and `shell_command.stdout` instead of `shell_command.rc`, the until will not work as expected.

I would be glad to see a pure Ansible implementation to this question (although I got the feeling that it won't be as straightforward as this).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand why we have to loop through random generation over the entire range while we only need to get a number from a specified range of integers with an excluded list. My understanding is that the solution is to use a simple difference to exclude the list from the range of accepted random values. An example playbook demonstrates this concept:

```yaml
---
- name: Excluded random
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    list: [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10]
  tasks:
    - name: Show list to exclude
      debug:
        var: list

    - name: Show random from excluded range
      debug:
        var: range(1,10) | difference(list) | random
```